# Running Oracle XE docker container with colima not working on Apple M2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arm, oracle-xe, apple-m2

I followed the steps in [this](https://blog.jdriven.com/2022/07/running-oracle-xe-on-apple-silicon/) blog post using colima, but I am still running into issues and I don't know what I'm missing.

Here is my docker-compose YAML file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    oracle:
        container_name: oracleDB
        image: gvenzl/oracle-xe:18
        platform: linux/amd64
        ports:
            - "1521:1521"
        environment:
            ORACLE_PASSWORD: "StrongPassword"
```

And this is the log:

```
CONTAINER: starting up...
CONTAINER: first database startup, initializing...
CONTAINER: uncompressing database data files, please wait...
CONTAINER: done uncompressing database data files, duration: 14 seconds.
CONTAINER: starting up Oracle Database...

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 08-AUG-2023 10:06:26

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/17fe1d08dc70/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                08-AUG-2023 10:06:26
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/17fe1d08dc70/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] 
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] 
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
CONTAINER: starting up...
CONTAINER: database already initialized.
CONTAINER: starting up Oracle Database...

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 08-AUG-2023 10:07:20

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/17fe1d08dc70/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                08-AUG-2023 10:07:22
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/17fe1d08dc70/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] 
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] 
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

I set up colima and started it like this:
`colima start --arch x86_64 --memory 4`

After that, I started the docker container and expected to work normally, but it seems like either the colima setup was not enough or there is some setup missing in the docker-compose YAML file. I'd appreciate a second pair of eyes for this.

Comment: Did you found any solution on this? Normally I managed to run but after a while it gave me the same error you faced. Do you have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're okay with Oracle EE and Docker you can build and run your own image for Apple Silicon:

[Oracle19c container is now running on Apple Silicon](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/2658).
Just follow the [Linux ARM64 instructions](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance).

```
% ./buildContainerImage.sh -v 19.3.0 -e
Oracle Database container image for 'ee' version 19.3.0 is ready to be extended: 
--> oracle/database:19.3.0-ee
Build completed in 207 seconds.
```